# C# MongoDB 2. Find document comparing its fields: unsupported filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to get documents from MongoDB such way:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<UnitModel>> GetUnits(string race)
    {
        var units = collection.Aggregate().Match(x => x.Race == race && 
            (x.Attack < x.Def1 || x.Attack < x.Def2) && 
            (x.UnitType == UnitType.Warrior || x.UnitType == UnitType.Archer));
        return await units.ToListAsync();
    }
```

But the following error occurs:

```
Unsupported filter: ({document}{attack} < {document}{def1}).
```

Using Where with the same predicate leads to the same result. What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

As far as I understand C# driver is unable to transform this query. Now I'm trying to use pipeline. First of all I tested the query in shell and it works:

```
db.units.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            cDiff: {$cmp: ['$attack','$def1']},
            iDiff: {$cmp: ['$attack','$def2']}
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                {race: "elf"},
                {$or: [
                    {
                        cDiff:{$eq:-1}
                    },
                    {
                        iDiff:{$eq:-1}
                    }
                ]},
                {$or: [{
                    "unitType": "Warrior"
                },
                {
                    "unitType": "Archer"
                }]}
            ]
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Now I'm stucked with transforming it to C#:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<UnitModel>> GetDeffenceUnits(Race race)
    {
        PipelineDefinition<UnitModel, UnitModel> pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
        {
            new BsonDocument{
                { "$addFields", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "iDiff:", new BsonDocument { { "$cmp", new BsonArray { "$attack", "$def1" } } } },
                        { "cDiff:", new BsonDocument { { "$cmp", new BsonArray { "$attack", "$def2" } } } }
                    }
                }
            },
            new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "$match", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {
                            "$and", new BsonArray
                            {
                                new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    { "race", race.GetEnumDisplayName() }
                                },
                                new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {
                                        "$or", new BsonArray
                                        {
                                            new BsonDocument
                                            {
                                                { "iDiff", new BsonDocument { { "$eq", -1 } } }
                                            },
                                            new BsonDocument
                                            {
                                                { "cDiff", new BsonDocument { { "$eq", -1 } } }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {
                                        "$or", new BsonArray
                                        {
                                            new BsonDocument
                                            {
                                                { "unitType", UnitType.Warrior.GetEnumDisplayName() }
                                            },
                                            new BsonDocument
                                            {
                                                { "unitType", UnitType.Warrior.GetEnumDisplayName() }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var units = collection.Aggregate(pipeline);                
        return await units.ToListAsync();
    }
```

This query returns an empty list. What did I miss?

---

**UPDATE 2**
Adding UnitModel:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class UnitModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // enum
    public Race Race { get; set; }
    public double Expenses { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }
    public double Capacity { get; set; }
    public double Attack { get; set; }
    public double Def1 { get; set; }
    public double Def2 { get; set; }
    // enum
    public UnitType UnitType { get; set; }
    public ResourcesModel TrainingCost { get; set; }
    public ResourcesModel ResearchCost { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ResearchTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TrainingTime { get; set; }
}

public class ResourcesModel
{
    public int Wood { get; set; }
    public int Gold { get; set; }
    public int Iron { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE 3**
trying to see the mongodb request:

```
        var units = collection.Aggregate(pipeline);
        var queryToMongo = units.ToString();
        return await units.ToListAsync();
```

**UPDATE 4**
Convention packs:

```
        var packEnum = new ConventionPack
        {
            new EnumRepresentationConvention(BsonType.String)
        };
        ConventionRegistry.Register("EnumStringConvention", packEnum, t => true);

        var packCamelCase = new ConventionPack
        {
            new CamelCaseElementNameConvention()
        };
        ConventionRegistry.Register("camel case",
                                    packCamelCase,
                                    t => t.FullName.StartsWith("TTB.DAL.Models"));
```

Comment: Can you add `UnitModel` too?

Comment: @Mahdi, updated

Comment: @NikitaFedorov you should be able to get and inspect the generated query using `collection.Aggregate(pipeline).ToString()`

Comment: Does every document contains Attack and Def1 properties? if not, try changing to nullable double and post your observations.

Comment: @jcruz ToString returns type name

Comment: @sam every document contains these values, but I tried, it didn't work: still empty list

Comment: Before returning, can you add line of code to know the query that is being sent to MONGO (var queryToMongo = units.ToString() ) and see whether your C# code making correct query or not. Have a debugger at line queryToMongo line, and then you can see the value in that variable.

Comment: @sam it returns MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AsyncCursor`1[DAL.Models.GameModels.UnitModel]

Comment: Could you post your code so I know where you have added var queryToMongo = units.ToString()

Comment: @sam I updated the post

Comment: @NikitaFedorov, what is data type of units? I am thinking its IAggregateFluent<BsonDocument> or IAggregateFluent<units>. when you say, units.ToString(), c# Mongo Driver will give you the query that you are executing against Mongo. Also, in your raw mongo query I see something by name iDiff and cDiff. But your UnitsModel does not have them. Are you using Bson Property initiatialization? I am asking these questions because to understand the picture.

Comment: @sam I'm not really strong in Mongo, but as I understand $addFields adds additional fields to the result document. In this case I'm saving in these fields comparison result between attack and def1, and attack and def2. Then I'm including these results into query to get only the units whose attack is less than at least one of the defense parameters. Then I realized that the problem may be related to deserialization of document into UnitModel, because UnitModel doesn't have iDiff and cDiff, so I added [BsonIgnoreExtraElements], that didn't help. I've added the ConventionPacks initialization

Comment: @sam type of units is MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AsyncCursor<TTB.DAL.Models.GameModels.UnitModel>, the driver version is 2.9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know, this is really embarrassing...when I copied my shell query to C#, I forgot to remove colons after iDiff and cDiff. After I removed them the query worked perfectly.